# NullPointerException for if(line[waitingLine].isEmpty()) --emptyLines;

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class ObjQueue<E> extends Vector<E>
{...}

ObjQueue<Customer>[] line=new ObjQueue[numServices];
...
if(line[waitingLine].isEmpty()) --emptyLines;
```

`NullPointerException` is for `if(line[waitingLine].isEmpty()) --emptyLines;` What's wrong?

Comment: Without seeing what happens between the second and third code lines in your sample it's not possible to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
new objQueue[numServices];
```

creates an array with all of its elements set to `null` — *not* an array of empty queues. So this:

```
line[waitingLine].isEmpty()
```

will invoke `isEmpty()` on `null`, unless you've explicitly initialized the elements of `line` in some way.

You probably want to follow this:

```
objQueue<Customer> [] line=new objQueue[numServices];
```

with this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numServices; ++i)
    line[i] = new objQueue<Customer>();
```

to initialize each element to a new, distinct queue.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely because `line[waitingLine]` is null, so you cannot call `isEmpty` on an null object. Your code to check should look like below:

```
...
if(line[waitingLine] != null && line[waitingLine].isEmpty())
...
```

I am assuming that the ... in your sample code means that you are placing values into the line array. However, if that is not the case, then you must fill those values in. When you instantiate an array, it merely allocates the space for the array. All of the array slots will essentially be filled with null until explicitly set.

Example code to fill in the waitingLine slot of line:

```
line[waitingLine] = new objQueue<Customer>();
```

You can explicitly fill ALL slots be creating a loop and placing the queue objects in each one.

However, if you want something that grows/shrinks dynamically, then you probably want to create a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead.

Comment: Doesn't objQueue<Customer> [] line=new objQueue[numServices]; initialise it? If not, then how should I do it?

Comment: Yes, it initializes it, as in it prepares it to have values submitted into it. But, as placeholders, all of the values will point to null until explicitly set

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class objQueue<E> extends Vector<E>
{...}

objQueue<Customer>[] line = new objQueue[numServices];
for(int i = 0; i < numServices; i++){
    line[i] = new objQueue<Customer>();
}
...
if(line[waitingLine].isEmpty()) --emptyLines;
```

Comment: the () result in Type mismatch: cannot convert from objQueue to objQueue<Customer>[], but without () it works.

Comment: See edit. Compiler will complain about unchecked conversion, but otherwise you should be fine.